# UIAlertView-like UIWindow

Tags: ios, uialertview, uiwindow

I want to make some kind of custom alert view - basically the same functions but different look. As far as I know, UIAlertView is being displayed in a separate window. I can create a window, put a view into it and display it, but it disappears just after the function returns, if there's no strong reference to the UIWindow object. On the other hand, there may be no strong reference to UIAlertView, but it does not disappear after it's shown. How can I achieve the same behavior for my alert window?

```
// create a new window
UIWindow *alertWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
alertWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert;

UIToolbar *background = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:alertWindow.frame];
background.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
background.translucent = YES;
[alertWindow addSubview:background];

[alertWindow addSubview:contentView];    
[alertWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you actually see this alertWindow? Because I can't get it on the screen, unless I call also `[self.view addSubview:alertWindow];` on the current ViewController.

**Second thing:**
If you need same functionality as `UIAlertView`, just subclass it.

**Third thing:**
If you need more customizable `UIAlertView`, than I would go with custom `UIView` and customize it. You can than show this alert on any UIViewController using delegates or if you prefer, NSNotificationCenter.

Answer (score 0):

> I can create a window, put a view into it and display it, but it disappears just after the function returns, if there's no strong reference to the UIWindow object.

You more or less answer your own question. Make sure there's a strong reference to the window.

`UIAlertView`'s internals are rather complicated, but there is a singleton that holds on to both the alert and the window it will be presented in. Every alert that's created calls to that singleton, so you could do something like that as well.